# HTML/JS site does not update html when using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I really don't know what I am doing wrong but my site just won't update the .innerHtml of the heading. There is no error in the browser console and console.log() returns the right string ("hhh").
Both elements with id = test and teet won't update their html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            test title
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="teet">TEST HEADING</h1>
        Search :
        <input id="input">
        <button onclick="load()" id="submit" type="button"> search </button>
        <br>
        <h1 id="test">  Test</h1>
        <script>
            function load() {
                var test = document.getElementById("test").innerHtml = "hhh";
                console.log(test);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's **innerHTML** with capital letters

Comment: oh god that was really stupid :D Thank you very much.